# How can i record audio using PhoneGap and store it in LocalStorage?

Tags: html, cordova

I want to capture audio file using PhoneGap in Android and iOS and then store it in Localstorage for playback.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Media API](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.media)? It allows you to record audio and store it. You probably won't be able to use localStorage though, at least not very easily, as localStorage can only store strings.

Comment: Use the media api as indicated by @AndrewLively. I suppose you could do all sorts of work to read in a recording and store it to `localStorage`, but you really, really, really don't want to. You'd have to convert it to base64 (since `localStorage` can only store strings), and you're going to run into limitations on the amount of data `localStorage` can handle (which, for audio, would add up in a hurry). The media API uses the persistent file system, and this, really, is where you ought to stay.

Answer (score 0):

With PhoneGap you can do this with HTML/JS using the PhoneGap API.

You can find the documentation for the audio functions [Phonegap doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html)

Comment: You aren't going to be storing this to `localStorage`, though -- rather the persistent file system.

Comment: I have implement the example from phonegap doc but getting error:
Error code = 3. means capture interrupted.